# How to use Firebase regular JavaScript SDK with Angular 2?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I want to use Firebase for an Angular2 app. Though AngularFire2 is there, it can't be integrated with normal quickstart example, gives various errors and it don't have the support for all the Firebase services.

Is there any way to use regular Javascript SDK with Angular 2 and use them in the methods of component classes?

I tried [this example](http://octomonkey.com/angular-2-services-with-observables-and-firebase/), there are some errors which couldn't be figured out.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the blog post you is using javascript SDK for Firebase **2**. AngularFire2 is using the upgraded Firebase **3** SDK. The syntax difference between 2 and 3 are fairly similar, but you would need to update the code to 3 in order for that example to work.